# Different results when computing a directed graph level centrality index

Tags: r, graph-theory

I just have started to work with graphs using R. I need to compute the eigenvector centrality metric and I ran into a problem. Given the following directed graph:

```
m = matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,
             0,0,1,0,0,
             0,0,0,0,1,
             0,1,0,0,0,
             1,0,0,0,15), byrow = T, nrow = 5)
g <-graph.adjacency(adjmatrix=m, diag=T)
```

I obtain different graph level centrality indexes for the same graph:

```
> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 0.9812478

> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 5.770555e-18

> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 0.9812478

> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 0.9812478

> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 3.472951e-18

> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 0.9812478

> centr_eigen(g, directed = T, scale = F,  options = arpack_defaults, normalized = T)$centralization
[1] 5.517527e-18
```

I am not sure if specifying the number of iterations or how the graph should be traversed would solve this problem. Is there other method to compute this centrality metric to gets the same result when computing it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

In general, eigenvector centrality relies on the centrality of individual nodes. The existence and uniqueness of these eigen solutions are a matter which I think usually belongs on math stack exchange.

In this case, a simple typo, in the (5,5) position of your adjacency matrix is the cause of this behavior. Rather than just saying that, I'll explain a bit.

You will notice that while centrality metric is bounded between 1 and 0, your adjacency matrix oscillates between 1 and 0 at the bounds. Why does you graph do this? A recurrent graph(chain) is guaranteed to return to it's original position with a finite hitting time. The one dimensional lattice always has a centrality of 0.

```
g <- make_ring(10, directed=FALSE)

g
    IGRAPH U--- 10 10 -- Ring graph
+ attr: name (g/c), mutual (g/l), circular (g/l)
+ edges:
 1-- 2 2-- 3 3-- 4 4-- 5 5-- 6 6-- 7 7-- 8 8-- 9 9--10 1--10
```

Why? Because the graph is moving from one node to the next with 100% probability.

```
centr_degree(g)$centralization
[1] 0
```

Your graph looks like this

```
g
IGRAPH D--- 5 20 -- 
+ edges:
 [1] 1->5 2->3 3->5 4->2 5->1 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5 5->5
```

It gets stuck at 5 with probability 15/16, and moves to 1 with probability of 1/16. If you fix this typo, your centrality is always calculated as `.719218`, which still indicates that this graph weighs node 5 heavily.

You might also note, that if you change the directed from `TRUE` to `FALSE` you will also avoid this problem, since it will calculate the shortest directed graph necessary to calculate the eigen centrality, of which it will always calculate `.959`.

Comment: I have tried this graph with 14 in the (5,5) position and it is not a problem, I always get 0.979762. I mean, 15 is not a typo. Can I compute the eigen centrality with multiple paths? I did small tests using other values than 1 in the adjacency matrix and the results were consistent and intuitive.

Comment: I thought you had meant to type 1 instead of 15. In an unweighted, undirected graph no adjacency matrix can have an element higher than 2. You have a heavily weighted graph. You need to change the argument `weighted` to TRUE in `graph.adjacency`.